# Converting NumPy Date in Pandas DataFrame without using Pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a question in an assessment where i have to convert NumPy data into Pandas dataframe type. It also should use the data's dtype names as column headers.

I cannot use the pd.DataFrame() function for this task and there has been a clue given where I am supposed to still use pandas methods.

This is the code i have so far -

```
    def convert_to_df(data):
        "converting numpy array into dataframe"
        far = data.tolist()
        return pd.Series(far).to_frame()
```

which does convert it to a DataFrame ,giving this with the test:

```
                                                   0
0  (2020-02-29 13:32:59, 1.23375E+18, 0.67, 0.293...
1  (2020-02-27 00:20:58, 1.23282E+18, 0.442, 0.38...
2  (2020-02-10 18:54:50, 1.22694E+18, 0.577, 0.42...
3  (2020-02-29 05:23:06, 1.23362E+18, 0.514, 0.41...
4  (2020-02-26 03:20:55, 1.23251E+18, 0.426, 0.37...
```

im just confused on how to then get the headers in order. My output when i run test code is meant to look like this.

```
            created_at  ...     emotion_category
0  2020-02-29 13:32:59  ...                  joy
1  2020-02-27 00:20:58  ...                 fear
2  2020-02-10 18:54:50  ...                  joy
3  2020-02-29 05:23:06  ...  no specific emotion
4  2020-02-26 03:20:55  ...                 fear

[5 rows x 9 columns]
```

I have attached a screenshot of the question so you can see the test codes and the wording.
Hope someone can help !

[image]

the data im using looks like this
[image]

Comment: They honestly make it so hard to actually enjoy the subject - yes apparently to make us explore different functions - spent many hours on this question and other trying to figure it out.

Comment: what is data? can you provide a python object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas series instead, what I would do is convert each column in the numpy array to a Series, for example, I have the following numpy array:

```
data = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
```

I will use a for loop to create series for each column:

```
series = []
for i in range(data.shape[1]):
    series.append(pd.Series(data[:,i], name="Serie_" + str(i)))
```

Finally, concatenate these series to one dataframe:

```
pd.concat([series[i] for i in range(data.shape[1])], axis=1)
```

The result:

```
   Serie_0  Serie_1  Serie_2
0        1        2        3
1        4        5        6
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
def convert_to_df(data):
    '''convert numpy to pandas'''
    headers = ['created_at', 'tweet_ID', 'valence_intensity', 'anger_intensity', 'fear_intensity',
             'sadness_intensity', 'joy_intensity', 'sentiment_category', 'emotion_category']

    df = data[:][headers[0]].tolist()
    df = pd.Series(df).to_frame()
    df.columns = ['created_at']
    for i in range(1, len(headers)):
        newcol = data[:][headers[i]].tolist()
        newcol = pd.Series(newcol).to_frame()
        df[headers[i]] = newcol
    return df
```